# Interpretation of eigenvalues calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I encounter the following formula to calculate eigenvalues:

$$(A - \lambda I)\cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$$

So here, what I undestand is that for non trivial solution, $\vec{v}$ has to be not null, so I have the following question. It seems that for this to be true, the matrix $A - \lambda I$ needs to have $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ . That means that this matrix needs to reduce the space of $\vec{v}$ However, I can't see this geometrically. How is the product of a matrix that reduces the dimension of the input vector equal to $\vec{0}$? We can't have the case when, after reducing the dimension, the product is not $\vec{0}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "the matrix reduces the space of $v$" or "matrix reduces the dimension of the input vector"? Do you mean that "the range of $A-\lambda I$ is not $n$-dimensional" (where the matrix is $n \times n$)?

Comment: You could rearrange this formula to get $Av = \lambda v$, so $v$ is mapped by $A$ onto a multiple of itself.

Comment: When you say “space of $\vec{v}$”, do you mean the subspace spanned by $\vec{v}$? The subspace spanned by a vector $\vec{v}$ is one dimensional. The image of that subspace under a linear transformation is another subspace. If that image has a smaller dimension, i.e. 0, then it must be only the origin, since it must be a subspace.

Comment: If $(A - \lambda I)\vec p = \vec q \ne \vec 0$, then the matrix $(A - \lambda I)$ maps the 2 dimension space spanned by $\vec v$ and $\vec p$ onto the one dimensional space of vectors parallel to $\vec q$

Comment: @angryavian [here](https://youtu.be/PFDu9oVAE-g?t=440) is where I saw it

Comment: It seems your question is basically about the connection between "the linear map defined by a square matrix A does not map its domain onto itself" and "a nontrivial solution to Ax=0 exists". One way to explain the connection is called the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily the matrix $A$ that is singular, but $A-\lambda I$ that has to be singular.  $A$ might also be singular, if any of the eigenvalues are $0$;  then the nontrivial eigenspace of $\lambda = 0$ is the null space of $A$.

$A$ acts on $v$ to produce $\lambda v$.

Comment: You have mixed up singular and nonsingular.

Comment: Thank you!  Embarrassing. Fixed.